# Differential algebra package in Mathematica

Tags: differential-equations, packages, maple

Is there any equivalent of [Maple's differential algebra package](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=DifferentialAlgebra) in Mathematica?

In particular, the Rosenfeld-Groebner algorithm has been implemented?

Comment: Maple is much superior to Mathematica, so instead of asking such packages in Mathematica that are well developed in Maple, you should start learning Maple if not started yet.

Comment: Possibly relevant would be the package [here](http://www.risc.jku.at/research/combinat/software/ergosum/RISC/HolonomicFunctions.html). This was posted to MSE in a [recent response to a different thread](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119306/51).