# Wilf-Zeilberger algorithm in Mathematica

Tags: special-functions, summation, algorithm, combinatorics, code-request

I am trying to prove the q-combinatorial identity
$$\sum_{s=0}^r(-1)^sq^{\frac{s(s+1)}{2}}{n-2r+s\brack n-2r}_q{n\brack r-s}_q=\sum_{s=0}^{r-1}(-1)^{s+1}q^{\frac{s(s+1)}{2}}{n-2r+s\brack n-2r}_q{n\brack r-s-1}_q,$$
where ${r\brack s}_q$ denotes q-binomial coefficients.
There is an algorithm called [Wilf-Zeilberger algorithm](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjC9ono2-LRAhWM0FQKHSsaDTYQFggfMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.306.5080%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&usg=AFQjCNGHd03Dpi2TIErOk--MrQIbRUofMg) which can used to prove such identities. Also Doron Zeilberger has written a  [Maple code](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/tokhniot/qEKHAD) that complete this task. Since I have never use Maple, I am looking for a Mathematica code that do the same job. Is there any such Mathematica code?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://www.risc.jku.at/research/combinat/risc/software/), ping *Peter Paule* for access...

Comment: @ciao: Thank you for your extremely helpful comment.  If you wish I would like to accept this as the answer for my question.

Comment: Also check [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119294/mathematica-implementation-of-zeilbergers-algorithm-previously-done-in-maple/119306#119306).

Comment: @Nil : thanks for sentiment, but seems a bit silly to get points for that. Hope it provides what you're looking for!

Comment: Even though the title of these two question are same, they not same. In fact my question is about the q- analogy of Wilf-Zeilberger algorithm. Also both underline Maple codes are very different