# symbolic Wilf-Zeilberger and hypergeometric series

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

It is possible transform the following sum as n tend to Infinity
$$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{2^{2 (k+1)-2} (-1)^{k-n+2} \Gamma \left(k+\frac{5}{2}\right) \Gamma (k+n+2) \, _2F_3\left(\frac{k}{2}+\frac{5}{4},\frac{k}{2}+\frac{7}{4};\frac{3}{2},\frac{k}{2}+\frac{3}{2},\frac{k}{2}+2;-\frac{1}{16}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi}\; \Gamma (2 (k+1)) \Gamma (k+3) \Gamma (-k+n+1)}=\sin \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$$
Using symbolic Wilf-Zeilberger , I try to get A G[k,n] from F[k,n] and acceleration the series Thanks

```
((-1)^(2+k-n) 2^(-2+2 (1+k)) Gamma[5/2+k] Gamma[2+k+n] HypergeometricPFQ[{5/4+k/2,7/4+k/2},{3/2,3/2+k/2,2+k/2},-(1/16)])/(Sqrt[\[Pi]] Gamma[2 (1+k)] Gamma[3+k] Gamma[1-k+n])


\sum _{k=0}^n \frac{x^k \left(\sqrt{\pi } (k-n-1)! (k+n+2)!\right)}{2 k! \left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)! (-n-1)! (n+2)!}
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE. I improve your chances for an answer, I suggest that you include copyable Mathematica code in your question, so that others don't have to type it. Also, please remember to upvote good answers and accept the answer, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mathematica implementation of Zeilberger's algorithm (previously done in Maple)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119294/mathematica-implementation-of-zeilbergers-algorithm-previously-done-in-maple)