# Verifying hypergeometric identity

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions

By experiments, it's easy to convince ourselves that the following expressions are identical for positive integer $n$.

```
i1=((3/4)^n n Gamma[2 n] (3^(1 + 2 n) n! + 
Gamma[2 + 3 n] 
Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[-n, 1 + 2 n,  2 (1 + n), -(1/3)]))/Gamma[2 + 3 n]
```

and

```
i2=(2 3^n Hypergeometric2F1[-n, 1 + 2 n, 2 (1 + n), 2/3])/(1 + 2 n)
```

and

```
i3 = 1/9 4^-n Sqrt[\[Pi]] (2 n)! ((3 Sqrt[3 \[Pi]])/(Gamma[2/3 + n] Gamma[4/3 + n]) +
HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{1, 2/3 + n, 4/3 + n}, {3/2 + n, 2 + n}, 1])
```

Unfortunately, FullSimplify does not simplify these expressions any further.

Is there anyway to show that they are actually the same?

Comment: I used this package to solve a similar problem, so it would likely work for you. Automated theorem prover for hypergeometric identities, written in Mathematica. Don't have it on my home computer, or I'd give it a shot. Will try tomorrow. https://www3.risc.jku.at/research/combinat/software/ergosum/RISC/fastZeil.html

Comment: Your question is also related to this one...https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119294/mathematica-implementation-of-zeilbergers-algorithm-previously-done-in-maple

Comment: @MikeY Isn't fastZeil used for reduce sums into hypergeometric functions? Here I don't have sum.

Comment: Your Hypergeometric terms are summations, so it should apply.

Comment: Usually I would use `DifferenceRootReduce[]` on these, but it seems to be not powerful enough for your problem. I second the recommendation to try out the RISC packages.

Comment: @MikeY Thanks, I have tried this. It takes a bit fiddling but indeed fastZeil works in these cases.

Comment: Oh, great. Glad it worked!